# How do I set up non-rectangular paper shapes for printing in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production, artboard, diecut

How can I design and set the correct page settings in Illustrator for print products like in these images? What will be the bleed measurement? [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really **ask the print shop** about how to set up your file. They should be able to send you a template of the punch form used and give you some guidance.

That said, **a PDF can only ever be rectangular**.

My *guess* would be that the print shop needs a file where the irregular shape touches the sides of the rectangle. The bleed is added all around the irregular shape.

Some examples:

[image]

The yellow area is your design, the cyan stroke is the document bounds and the magenta stroke is where the final print is punched.

Comment: Thank you so much. one of my clients want  this shape but as i have no previous project like this  so i have no idea at all...i have no clue about who gonna be responsible for this shape the printing company or the designer(me) <3 Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. Just be careful. Some punching methods require a physical hand made metal form. You can't just design any form. You need to get in contact with the printing company. And just to be clear: The cyan and magenta strokes aren't supposed to be present on the finished print file.

Comment: i need to clear one thing. so am gonna design the whole thing as usual like  i do regularly on a rectangular object in illustrator... and the printing guy gonna change the live corner widget to get the shape? i mean as a designer am not responsible for those round corner?

Comment: i dnt know why i cant tag you :( @wolff

Comment: @suraiyaabedin You don't have to tag the answerer if you are leaving a comment on an answer--they will get a notification anyway.

Comment: Thank you vincent :) i didnt know

Comment: Oh, don't focus so much on the round corners. Essentially you just need to make sure, that if you print your design and the punch is a little off (1-3 mm), there won't be any white paper visible. Maybe you can just fill out the entire rectangle with color. So the example with the circular design would just be a yellow square. Again, you should really ask the print house these questions to be sure.

Comment: Agreed. I fell into packaging working in biscuits, music and a plumbing supply company in Germany (setting in a foreign language to my own). Creating various point of sale, boxes, wraps. SOP was to ask the printer / box supplier for their template (with bleed all around the shape) and then create art to sit over this. I'd supply art clean and with a transparent line template so that they could see it was registered OK. If there was no template, the printer's repro' team would make one (for bespoke boxes) - as in this example (repro / printed in China) : https://bit.ly/39v2AXj

Comment: @Wolff this thing is interesting, that cyan and magenta lines. 1) Cyan line == Document size? 2) The magenta lines are for designer's guide only? Since you're saying you dont' send it in final print file.

Comment: @Vikas, I explain it in the last sentence of the answer. Cyan = document bounds/document size, magenta = the final shape of the product.

Answer (score 5):

What Wolff said is correct. Also, brochures like this cost extra typically where I'm from, because of its unique form.

When you set up a print file, there should be three main lines:

- die line: where the paper will be cut giving you the final shape and size
- safe line (safe zone): usually .125 inches *within* the die line. Make sure your art does not surpass this line or it may be too close to the edge and risk getting cut off
- bleed line: usually .125 inches *outside* of the die line. Make sure art that you want going to the edges actually reaches the bleed line, not just the die line.

Lastly, make sure the printer does not print your lines!! Set your line layers to "Template" (double click layer for this option) or label the layer as "Do not print." You can also state to not print those lines. However, if the printer sends you the die line, they may have all these layers set up appropriately already.

[image: screen shot of illustrator how to set up print layers]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Layers stay as it is in PDF since we don't send AI files?